# How to change the value of option with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote the below code for a booking flight and it works good.

My only problem is that I can not change the value of each option of each `select`.

For example : I want to set value from `0` to `12` to each `option`. But it only repeated the value of inside option's tags.

How can I set value specially for options not only repeat the text inside them as value? 
how can i do this?
here is my snippet:

```js
$(function() {

  // Function to create child dropdown
  var createChildDropdown = function(i) {
  
    // Create a div in the following format:
    // <div class="childs">
    //    <label for="...">Child (number)</label>
    //    <select id="..."></select>
    // </div>
    var $childDropdown = $('<div />', {
      'class': 'childs'
    });
    $childDropdown.append($('<label />', {
      'for': 'childDropdown-' + i
    }).text('Child ' + i));
    $childDropdown.append($('<select />', {
      'id': 'childDropdown-' + i
    }));
    
    // Define options made available for each child
    var options = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    options.forEach(function(option) {
      // Create new option element and append to <select>
      $childDropdown.find('select').append($('<option />').text(option).attr('value', option));
    });
    
    // Return documentFragment so that we can append it
    return $childDropdown;
  };
  
  // Function to destroy child dropdown
  var destroyChildDropdown = function($el, i) {
    $el.find('div.childs').get(i).remove();
  };

  $(".button-click a").on("click", function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var oldVal = parseInt(button.closest("ul").prev().val());
    var newVal = (button.text() == "+") ? oldVal + 1 : (oldVal > 0) ? oldVal - 1 : 0;
    var total_value = "";

    button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);

    $(".travel").each(function() {
      var cat = $(this).prev('span').text();
      total_value += cat + ": " + $(this).val() + ", ";
    });

    if (oldVal < newVal) {
      $('.childDropdowns').append(createChildDropdown(newVal));
    } else if (oldVal > newVal) {
      destroyChildDropdown($('.childDropdowns'), newVal);
    }

    total_value = total_value.substring(0, total_value.length - 2);
    $(".main").val(total_value);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
Count all1 Traveller(s)
<input type="text" name="no_travellers" class="main" value="Adults: 1" placeholder="" />
</label>
<br/>
<label>
   <span>Children</span>
   <input type="text" class="travel" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672"  value="0" />
   <ul class="button-group button-click">
      <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
   </ul>
</label>
<div class="childDropdowns"></div>
```

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking. What is `if (oldVal < newVal) {` in the first script block supposed to achieve? Where did you previously define the variables `oldVal` and `newVal`?

Comment: this code makes for me selectbox with options. i want to change the value of each option . eg : <option value="0">a</option> . in this code the value of each option replaced with the text inside in it

Comment: _“this code makes for me selectbox with options”_ - no, it doesn’t. It only throws an error, because neither `oldVal` nor `newVal` exist at this point.

Comment: @CBroe please see my updated snippet

Comment: So the problem is that you get the same value and text content for your newly created options? Well yeah, when you _set_ the same for both, using `.text(option).attr('value', option)`, that is what happens, should not be a surprise ... so if you want the options to have a different text, then _set_ a different text …?

Comment: @CBroe yes . i want to set different values from my text. i have a,b,c,d,e,f, for options but i want to set values for them like : 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: Well then simply get the loop counter of your forEach loop, and set that …?

Comment: how ? i tried but i can't

Comment: The loop counter is passed into your callback function as a second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forEach passes the loop index to your callback function as a second parameter - so all you need to do is make your callback *take* that second parameter, and then use it as the value:

```js
$(function() {

  // Function to create child dropdown
  var createChildDropdown = function(i) {
  
    // Create a div in the following format:
    // <div class="childs">
    //    <label for="...">Child (number)</label>
    //    <select id="..."></select>
    // </div>
    var $childDropdown = $('<div />', {
      'class': 'childs'
    });
    $childDropdown.append($('<label />', {
      'for': 'childDropdown-' + i
    }).text('Child ' + i));
    $childDropdown.append($('<select />', {
      'id': 'childDropdown-' + i
    }));
    
    // Define options made available for each child
    var options = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    options.forEach(function(option, index) {
//-> added parameter name index here ^^^^^ 
      // Create new option element and append to <select>
      $childDropdown.find('select').append($('<option />')
             .text(option).attr('value', index));
//-> and using it here ...               ^^^^^
    });
    
    // Return documentFragment so that we can append it
    return $childDropdown;
  };
  
  // Function to destroy child dropdown
  var destroyChildDropdown = function($el, i) {
    $el.find('div.childs').get(i).remove();
  };

  $(".button-click a").on("click", function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var oldVal = parseInt(button.closest("ul").prev().val());
    var newVal = (button.text() == "+") ? oldVal + 1 : (oldVal > 0) ? oldVal - 1 : 0;
    var total_value = "";

    button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);

    $(".travel").each(function() {
      var cat = $(this).prev('span').text();
      total_value += cat + ": " + $(this).val() + ", ";
    });

    if (oldVal < newVal) {
      $('.childDropdowns').append(createChildDropdown(newVal));
    } else if (oldVal > newVal) {
      destroyChildDropdown($('.childDropdowns'), newVal);
    }

    total_value = total_value.substring(0, total_value.length - 2);
    $(".main").val(total_value);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
Count all1 Traveller(s)
<input type="text" name="no_travellers" class="main" value="Adults: 1" placeholder="" />
</label>
<br/>
<label>
   <span>Children</span>
   <input type="text" class="travel" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672"  value="0" />
   <ul class="button-group button-click">
      <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
   </ul>
</label>
<div class="childDropdowns"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: do you have any suggestion to add ontill 4 ?

Comment: Don’t understand what you mean.

Comment: i want to decrease only to 4 .

Comment: Still makes no sense. “Decrease” what, where is anything getting “decreased” here?

Comment: well in the textbox. when i click on plus the number added. i want to add  just to  4

Comment: You mean you want to limit this to a maximum of 4 such “Child X” select fields? Well then you have to keep a counter, or dynamically count the number of already existing ones ... but that is a bit too broad for the scope of _this_ particular question now.